# How to put single-***.php in a specific folder?

Tags: themes, single

I am organizing and cleaning my code to make it easier to maintain. It turns out that my site has a lot of custom post types, so I have about fifteen single-***.php files at the root of my site. In order to make the tree view cleaner, I would like all of these files to be listed in a specific "single" folder.

Obviously, Wordpress only recognizes the single-***.php files that are at the root of a theme. Is there a way around this?

Thanking you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Changing how WordPress loads files can be very difficult and potentially destroy logic other plugins rely on. Instead, I usually make use of [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) in this case like so

**single.php**

```
<?php

get_template_part('singles/single', get_post_type());
```

And your files like

- singles/single-foo.php (for CPT foo)
- singles/single-bar.php (for CPT bar)
- singles/single.php (this is the default)